# Strange JavaScript notation, all parenthesis and brackets

Tags: javascript

So I participated in a Capture The Flag this week and one of the challenges really confused me.

[Challenge file (.txt)](https://ictf.openwest.org/files/a222bc8bbfde1fc6a3f12af14d4a0c21/challenge3.txt)

Preview:

> [][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+

This was the file given, it reminded me of [this](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-perl-737.html), after playing with it for a bit I entered it into the JavaScript console on my browser and an alert with the flag popped up.

If someone could explain why this works, and how I could create something like this. Also is it simple to translate this into normal looking JavaScript, I just imagine this could be a way for an attacker to execute sketchy code in my browser.

Comment: JavaScript often behaves in ways that are [unexpected](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). You'll need to understand what things like `[]+[]` and `[]-[]` do to crack this code.

Comment: That's [**jsFuck**](http://www.jsfuck.com/) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck)). It is used sometimes to obfuscate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i put some link that could be helpful

- [transaltejs](https://gist.github.com/mgechev/4188098) (github code) translate string into this pattern
- [explanetion 1](http://www.jsfuck.com), jsfuck
- [explanation 2](https://blog.mgechev.com/2013/02/22/javascript-the-weird-parts/), JavaScript, the weird parts

the key to do this

- false       =>  ![]
- true        =>  !![]
- undefined   =>  [][[]]
- NaN         =>  +[![]]
- 0           =>  +[]
- 1           =>  +!+[]
- 2           =>  !+[]+!+[]
- 10          =>  [+!+[]]+[+[]]
- Array       =>  []
- Number      =>  +[]
- String      =>  []+[]
- Boolean     =>  ![]
- Function    =>  []["filter"]
- eval        =>  []["filter"]"constructor"()
- window      =>  []["filter"]"constructor"()